# Not able to access a firebase collection after publishing security rule

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I was trying to access data from Cloud Firestore, but the access is denied.

My flutter code

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final logineduser = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
    final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('product_details').get();
final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.docs;
print(documents[0]);
```

The Cloud Firestore Security rules

```
rule_version='2'
service colud.firestore{
   match /databases/{database}/documents {

     match /user_details/{emailId}{
        allow read,write;
     }

     match /user_activities/{userId}{
        allow read,write;
     }

     match /product_details/{Id}{
        allow read,write;
     }

     match /purchase_details/{Id}{
        allow read,write;
     }

     match /{document=**}{
        allow read,write:if request.auth.uid !=null;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: At first glance it looks like the read should be allowed by the rules. Can you edit your question to show the exact error message and stack trace you get?

Answer (score 0):

This says to allow read or write if the authentication is not null.. So unless the user is authenticated you will not be able to access data except for the queries you have written above this. You can either implement login or to make it public you can write

```
allow read,write;
```

Please note it is NOT a good practice to keep it public. Maybe for learning you can try this.

Comment: In rules any [overlapping paths OR'ed together](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements), in which case the `allow read,write;` OP has on `product_details` would take precedence over their auth requirement. Or am I misunderstanding your explanation?